# How do I verify that the snapshot is ongoing for a particular index in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a business need to drop and re-create indices with new mappings. I have been doing that successfully until I encountered the following problem:

`Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot.`

1. How do I check if the snapshot is ongoing?
2. How do I cancel the currently running snapshot?

Is there a Java API for it? I am using version 6.01.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Get all running snapshots using
   `GET /_snapshot/_status`
2. Deletion of a running snapshot will stop and then delete the snapshot: `DELETE /_snapshot/my_repository/snapshot_to_stop`

Source: [snapshot api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/modules-snapshots.html)

There is no offical java api supporting rhe snapshot and restore module but you can easily issue a http call using the [official http rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html)

Answer (score 0):

Curl commands based on the answer mentioned above :-

1. Get all running snapshots using :

   curl -X GET "https://domain_endpoint_url/_snapshot/_status"
2. Deletion of a running snapshot will stop and then delete the snapshot:

   curl -X DELETE "https://domain_endpoint_url/_snapshot/snapshot-repository-name/snapshot-name"